# Want to write customized error and output function in shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I want to pass the standard error and standard output to userdefined function to write the custom logs

```
    OutputLogFile="OutputLogFilepath"   
    ErrorLogFile="ErrorLogfilePath"  
    //user defined function  
    OutputLog()  
    {  
    echo $(DateTimeForLog)-$ScriptName-”information”-$1 >> $StdOutPutlogFile  
    }    
    errorLog()  
    {  
    echo $(DateTimeForLog)-$ScriptName-”error”-$1 >> $StdErrorLogFile   
     }  
   //commands   
    {
    ls -la  
    cd /tmp/kjhdakdha  
    ls -la  
    } 2 | errorLog 1 | OutputLog
```

I want to capture the customised log instead of direct error and output. But above code is not working.

Comment: *not working* is not a diagnostic aid.  Help yourself and show the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection at the end of the block is syntactically incorrect.  I won't bore you with the rest of your (incomplete) script, here is the last line:

```
} 2> >(errorLog 1) 1> >(OutputLog)
```

You omitted the redirection symbol `>`, and you should read-up on  [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

The `1` in front of `>` is usually omitted, but used here it aids readability.  I'm not sure if the `1` after `errorLog` call was meant to do that or is a parameter to the function, so omit it if it is not required.

As @Veda reminded me, I should have mentioned that your functions do not redirect the actual output or error message.  Here is an example:

```
OutputLog()
{  
  while IFS='' read -r
  do
    echo "$(DateTimeForLog)-$ScriptName-information- $REPLY" >> "$StdOutPutlogFile"
  done
}
```

Comment: Use something like `read IN; echo "output: $IN"` in your `OutputLog` function to use the output.

Comment: Hi cdarke, for the above process substitution, am getting the below error.'>(' unexpected. My actual requirement is i need to customize the standard error and output in my log file by adding date-scriptname-error or information- actual stderr or std output message.

Comment: Hi cdarke and Veda, Thank u so much for your help.                                                { 2> errorLog - syntax is working perfectly and am using read IN inside the function to capture the logs. That also working perfectly. Thank you :).